# Sudo password not required? OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, root, sudo

I recently upgraded to a Macbook Pro Retina running OS X 10.8.3. I was going through the process of installing various command line tools when I noticed that it wasn't asking for my root password when executing sudo commands. Is this normal? It makes me a bit nervous (an unlocked laptop gives complete root access to my machine).

Comment: Not at all? Or just once and then not again for some time?

Answer (score 2):

sudo only requires your password the first time, or if you don't use it for 5 minutes.